# How to properly configure a missing symbol in Java import statement?

Tags: java, import, base64, classpath

I recently got this error:

```
chan@TakShing:~/Desktop/Java$ javac test.java
test.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String( user_pass.getBytes() );
                 ^
  symbol:   variable Base64
  location: class test
1 error
```

So I went around websites and found out that you have to download the source file which I have from: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

I downloaded "**commons-codec-1.10-src.tar.gz**" under "Source", but I am completely stuck on how to proceed with the final step of getting everything connected. I am currently on Ubuntu as well.

I admit that I have seen some posts saying to set the classpath, but I do not understand because all the answers I found were "set classapth" and that's it. The problem is I have no idea how to do that and I am a total amateur when it comes to doing this technical stuff and especially on Ubuntu. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Instead of downloading the src, get the compiled version of commons-codec. Then extract that archive, inside you should find a jar file you will need to add to your classpath.

Comment: I only installed all the necessary stuff to get java working on ubuntu today, so I am not sure if classpath exists if I have to make this manually?

Comment: You have several options; maven is a sophisticated build tool which can do it for you. At a minimum, you should read the [PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) section of the Java Tutorials.

Comment: Be aware that `user_pass.getBytes()` is dangerous.  It will use the underlying platform’s default charset to convert characters to bytes, which means you’ll get different bytes for the same value on different machines.  It is highly advisable to use `user_pass.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to download any packages or anything provided you already have the java JDK installed. You just forgot to import the Base64 package.

At the top of your document, write:
`import java.util.Base64` and you should be fine and dandy.

---

### Update

I re-wrote your code to conform to [Java's Base64 package.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)

```
import java.util.Base64;

String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(user_pass.getBytes());
```

Comment: I only downloaded the source, and I am trying to use "import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;"

Comment: Try using `java.util.Base64` instead. The encoding is base64 regardless of where you get it from, so both should work, but this way you don't need to install any extra packages and superfluous imports. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I'm trying to use the function 'Base64.encodeBase64String()"

Comment: Check the update I made. I'm guessing you found the apache Base64 package from a previous post, but it's fairly outdated now. Please try the code. It will save you from a bunch of pain with classpaths etc.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of trouble and probably even more if I kept searching how to do it.